# replace all '*' with spaces EXCLUDING org headers?

Tags: org-mode, regular-expressions

I converted a file to `org-mode`, but have a lot of extra asterisks.  I want to replace each * with a space, but I want to exclude the * in a header line.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function, minimally tested, uses
a
[regular expression](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression) search
and replace, but conditions the replace on not being in an `org`
header.  Note that it doesn't treat the `*` bullets in a plain
list as special: if you want to keep them, too, you'll need to
modify the function (try with`org-at-item-p`):

```
(defun bullets-to-spaces ()
  "Replace * with a space except in org headers."
  (interactive)
  (save-restriction
    (save-excursion
      (widen)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward "\\*" nil t)
        (unless (org-at-heading-p)
          (replace-match " "))))))
```

Comment: perfect! works very well